# Xpath getattribute and click action not selecting element

Tags: xpath

I am using selenium webdriver

I am trying to click on an element or trying to get the value of the href  but to no avail
The href give me the url of the page and not 'Time & Attendance' as I would expect

```
String Hrefvalue=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(@id,'EmploymentTab') ] //*[contains(@class,'TabDown')][4]/a")).getAttribute("href");
System.out.println(Hrefvalue);
```

The xpath above works fine and finds the element when I use firebug and select the element when I inspect it with firebug but that is as far as I get, it will not click it or it will not output the href?

The source is

Time & Attendance

This is probably a shot in the dark but if you could help me it would be great

Thanks

Comment: The source is
<td class="TabDown" nowrap="">
<a class="PLAIN" onclick="return ToggleTab(4)" href="#">Time & Attendance</a>

Answer (score 0):

Anyway I think problem is in xpath, may be it selects several elements. 
May be this will help:

```
String href = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[text()='Time & Attendance']")).getAttribute("href");
```